# where is the session created in Mask-RCNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I am learning deep learning for object detection and segmentation. Hence, I am  trying to understand the theory of Mask-RCNN but also the associated code. I follow this GitHub, more specifically, the `sample/balloon/ballon.py`: https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN

One thing that I really dont understand, is where the session was created? I was expecting to have it in the `mrcnn/model.py`, but I dont find it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keras deals with sessions implicitly, which means you mostly don't need to worry about it.

If you want to fetch the current session, you can use:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.get_session().
```

If you want to define a tensorflow session and make Keras use it to initialize all variables:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()

from keras import backend as K
K.set_session(sess)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @sdcbr for your answer! But in both of your case there is the word session, which I can not find in the mask-rcnn GitHub files…

Comment: Because you can write entire scripts using Keras without ever having to deal with sessions explicitly. My examples were just intended to illustrate how you *could* do it, but it's not required in most common cases.

Comment: My issue, is that I would like to add :config.gpu_options.allocator_type = 'BFC' somewhere to deal with a OutOfMemory problem… but I have no idea where to add as I can not see any session. Moreover I still dont understand why we have the choice to create a session or not.

Comment: Keras always creates a session, we do not need to do it manually and we even don't get to see it explicitly. If needed, the current session can be accessed through `K.get_session()`